Sobolev space on a curve
Let $D \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a convex set with $\partial D = \gamma([0,1])$ for some smooth curve.
One can define $H^{k}(\partial D)$ as the trace of Sobolev functions on $D$.
Let $f \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be some function. Clearly this defines a function $\tilde{f}$ on $\partial D$. What is the correct expression for the norm of $\tilde{f}$ in $H^k(\partial D) $ in terms of an integral on $[0,1]$.
For $k = 0$ this should be an identity along the lines of
$\int_{\partial D} |\tilde{f}(x)|^2 d x = \int_0^1 |f(\alpha)|^2 |\dot{\gamma}(r)| d r.$
I know that the general case of Sobolev Spaces on boundaries of smooth sets is related to a partition of unity and a change of coordinates. I am wondering if there is a reference or argument for treating this simpler case.
